# How do I close a window using ctypes python

Tags: windows, python-3.x, windows-10, ctypes

I've been trying to make a program in python using the package ctypes that goes something like this:

```
import ctypes
import os

os.system("hello.mp3")
```

Then it opens Groove Music and plays the music file.

But what I want it to do is close the music file after playing.

How can I do this?

P.S It doesn't matter if it's not using the ctypes package

Comment: `os.system` will run the command you enter using cmd.exe if you have another application on your PC that you can run from cmd that automatically closes after the file finishes playing you could likely just use `os.system('application.exe ' + filename)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the mp3play module.

https://pypi.org/project/mp3play/

It would be something like

```
import mp3play as mP

file = 'C:\path\to\your\*.mp3'
song = mP.load(file)

song.play()
```

Comment: Thank for input, but when I run that it keeps on giving me an error